# WebPack-Dev-Server error: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack itself is working fine, but the webpack-dev-server is not. Basically, webpack created 2 build files for me, a back-end bundle and a front-end bundle. So, I have a webpack-config.js for each of these. I want to develop my front-end code with webpack-dev-server, as you can see from my webpack-config file for my front-end-bundle.js below. When I run web-pack-dev server, it is able to find and build my front-end.js and index.html, but nothing renders in the console and it gives me a **"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"**

```
// var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry: './browser/entry.js',
output: {
    path: './builds',
    filename: 'frontend.js'
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': '"development"'
        }
    })
],
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: [/\.es6$/, /\.js$/, /\.jsx$/],
            exclude: 'node_modules',
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
            }
        }, 
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader'
        }, 
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        }, 
    ]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6', '.json'], 
    root: '/Users/johnhenry/Desktop/GAMR/gamr/browser'
}, 
devServer: {
    contentBase: 'builds/dev-build'
},
target: 'node',
// externals: [nodeExternals()]
}
```

The error is triggered by this in my front-end build (it is only in the dev server build, not in the non-dev-server webpack build):

```
function(module, exports) {

module.exports = require("url");
```

If anyone has insight into this, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 14):

Try adding:

```
target: 'web'
```

to your module block.

Comment: For me, this throws *Can't resolve 'fs'*.
The `node: { fs: "empty", }` suggestion throws *_fs2.default.readFileSync is not a function*. See [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447).

Comment: I know I already upvoted, but this solved the "Require not defined" issue for me with `webpack-dev-middleware` also. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and if anyone is still struggling with this, this solution also helped me:

> ... There are 2 ways to solve the issue:
>
> **1. (Recommended) Don't activate webpack-node-externals in your Webpack browser config, but let Webpack indeed bundle those modules
> when targeting the web (this is probable what you want to do)**
>
> 2. Have the external modules loaded in some other way in the browser, and add the appropriate importType flag to the webpack-node-externals configuration (either var for scripts or amd for AMD)

more details here: https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals/issues/17#issuecomment-284222729

Answer (score 2):

I hit this issue when a webpack.config.js from a node app for the base of a react app.

I had the following:

```
target: 'web'
```

but still ran in to the same issue.

Removing reference to **webpack-node-externals** solved it, which does make sense when you think about what node-externals is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had below rule in my webpack.config.js

```
 rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use:['script-loader']
        }
    ]
```

Removing above rule from webpack.config.js removed the error.

Hope this helps.